# Why i can not get this value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why I can not get this value in javascript ?

When I mouseover TEST , it's will alert `110`

Why not alert `111-1`

```js
function xxx(value)
{
alert(value);
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="xxx(111-1)">TEST</div>
```

Comment: @tymeJV No there isn't

Comment: um… because 111-1 is 110…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put string in quotes

```html
<div onmouseover="xxx('111-1')">TEST</div>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function xxx(value)
{
alert(value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Because *math.*

JS parses `111 - 1` as `110` as everyone else does because they're numbers. Make it a string if you want it as is.

```
xxx("111-1");
```

Also you don't need `language` attribute nowadays as javascript is widely(or everywhere?) supported and inline-js isn't advisable. Use event handlers instead.

Comment: can i apply for alert 111-1

Comment: @robertwersaq `alert("111-1")` will alert `"111-1"` while `alert(111 - 1)` will alert `110`